# associative array foreach loop to load required files

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to load all my files in `'config.php'` using an associative array. the different values denote where the file can be found. However I keep getting an error output of:

> Could not load: array.php, array.php, array.php, array.php, dir.php,
>   dir.php, dir.php, dir.php, auth.php, auth.php, auth.php, auth.php,
>   forms.php, forms.php, forms.php, forms.php, image.php, image.php,
>   image.php, image.php, navigation.php, navigation.php, navigation.php,
>   navigation.php, stats.php, stats.php, stats.php, stats.php,
>   tables.php, tables.php, tables.php, tables.php, text.php, text.php,
>   text.php, text.php, user.php, user.php, user.php, user.php,
>   youtube.php, youtube.php, youtube.php, youtube.php, messages.php,
>   messages.php, messages.php, messages.php, nemesis.php, nemesis.php,
>   nemesis.php, nemesis.php, upload.php, upload.php, upload.php,
>   upload.php, construct.php, construct.php, construct.php,
>   construct.php, prepared_arrays.php, prepared_arrays.php,
>   prepared_arrays.php, prepared_arrays.php

I am not sure why this is happening, nor why it states the file could not load 4 times.

```
<?php
    $require = array(
        'array.php' => 'f',
        'dir.php' => 'f',
        'auth.php' => 'f',
        'forms.php' => 'f',
        'image.php' => 'f',
        'navigation.php' => 'f',
        'stats.php' => 'f',
        'tables.php' => 'f',
        'text.php' => 'f',
        'user.php' => 'f',
        'youtube.php' => 'f',
        'messages.php' => 'c',
        'nemesis.php' => 'c',
        'upload.php' => 'c',
        'construct.php' => 't',
        'prepared_arrays.php' => 'l'
    );

    load($require);

    function load($require) {
        foreach ($require as $filename => $directory) {
            // init functions
            if ($directory = 'f') {
                $prep = FUNCTIONS_DIR . $filename;
                if (is_file($prep) && is_readable($prep)) {
                    require($prep);
                    $pass[] = $filename;
                } else {
                    $fail[] = $filename;
                }
            }
            // init classes
            if ($directory = 'c') {
                $prep = CLASSES_DIR . $filename;
                if (is_file($prep) && is_readable($prep)) {
                    require($prep);
                    $pass[] = $filename;
                } else {
                    $fail[] = $filename;
                }
            }
            // init templates
            if ($directory = 't') {
                $prep = TEMPLATES_DIR . $filename;
                if (is_file($prep) && is_readable($prep)) {
                    require($prep);
                    $pass[] = $filename;
                } else {
                    $fail[] = $filename;
                }
            }
            // init libs
            if ($directory = 'l') {
                $prep = LIBS_DIR . $filename;
                if (is_file($prep) && is_readable($prep)) {
                    require($prep);
                    $pass[] = $filename;
                } else {
                    $fail[] = $filename;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($fail)) {
            if (!empty($pass)) {
                $passed  = implode(', ', $pass);
                $message = "Loaded: {$passed}";
                echo $message;
            }
            if (!empty($fail)) {
                $failure = implode(', ', $fail);
                $message = "Could not load: {$failure}";
                echo $message;
            }
            exit();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Double checked the paths?

Comment: This seems like a lot more trouble than just listing the files individually and non-intuitive to anyone else who might want to work on your code.  What are you trying to achieve here? You are already spending time trying to debug why this doesn't work, whereas you could have just written the requires and been done with with.  It is not like you are gaining any extra flexibility here either as every time you need to add a new include you have to make a code change to do so.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this in a comment, but, in your `load` function before the first if, you can put a `switch` to check the `$directory` and set a var with its matching constant, and concat it on prep. This way you don't have to repeat all thoso `if`s along your code. They are the same. Just a refactor tip.

Comment: @mikebrant its mainly so i can verify that the files do infact exist, and i am going to add additional functionality later.

Comment: @dontvotemedown thats an interesting take, however then you still have to define the switch like case this and a break, so in the end it ends up being the same amount of code?

Comment: @Alex if the case is that you want to application to still run when a require fails, then you really should be using `include` and not `require`. Require should really be used in case where you want your application to halt when the file is not found (so no need to check for file existence and such).

Comment: im aware. and believe me if any of these files dont get loaded. i dont want it to run. i do however, want to know where the issue is

Comment: @Alex You could also simply set up an error handler to handle include warnings and then exit the app if the error handler is triggered (with appropriate messaging). All of which seem more straightforward than writing a bunch of logic to do something that PHP gives you for free if using require (i.e. ending script execution and giving you message on bad require). Your error log and/or your screen will give you output on failed requires (depending how you have set up error notifications in PHP).

Comment: @Alex I believe not. This is what is in my mind: http://pastebin.com/JY9fmR86

Answer (score 4):

`$directory = 'l'` **should be** `$directory == 'l'` **:)**

**PS**: *Same applies to all your comparisons. They are comparisons, not assignments.*